# JoanZapata/android-pdfview, Blank pdf shows

Tags: android, pdf

When I tried to view the specific pdf. Pdf data does not display, only the blank white screen shows without any error. I am using JoanZapata/android-pdfview 1.0.2, Android 4.0 and test it on Nexus 7, Nexus 4 and Samsung S5.

Comment: Did you write `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> ` in your manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

Could you give more information on that? Maybe some code, screenshot, info on the PDF file would be nice.

I would say the PDF encoding might be the problem.